# Django authenticate user is not working

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am athenticating user and redirecting him to index page:

```
def sign_user(request):
    username = request.POST['login']
    password = request.POST['pwd']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        print('success:' + username + " " + password)
        return redirect('/')
```

this is index view:

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    print(user)
```

And as a result here I get: AnonymousUser

What do I do?

Comment: Where do you get `AnonymousUser`? Just in `index` or also in `sign_user`? Try adding `print(user)` before redirecting.

Comment: added print before redirecting - it printed user login like needed

Comment: @Ralf also in sign_user =)

Comment: Added an answer to this post: you need to login the user.

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to login the user, like the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) say.

```
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way,

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


def sign_user(request):
    username = request.POST['login']
    password = request.POST['pwd']
    try:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')  # login success
    except:
        return redirect('unable to login')
```